# Django times out instead of returning exception

Tags: python, django, reverse-proxy, gunicorn

I've got a remote server running Nginx -> gunicorn -> django.  When I hit a view that causes an exception, I would expect a `500 server error` page to be returned.  Instead, it hangs for ~10 seconds and I get a `502 bad  gateway`.

When I look in the gunicorn logs, they indicate a worker timed out and was killed.  No exceptions are logged, and no admin emails are sent.  The gunicorn logs:

```
[2016-02-16 16:47:30 -0600] [5809] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:5817)
[2016-02-16 22:47:30 +0000] [5817] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5817)
[2016-02-16 16:47:30 -0600] [5833] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5833
```

On my local machine, everything works as expected.  They are both running identical `settings.py` (DEBUG is False).  I reduced it to a test case of

```
def foo(request):
    raise Exception('bar')
```

Browsing to it locally, it immediately returns the 500 server error page, as well as firing off admin emails.  On the remote server, the browser spins for a while then nginx returns the bad gateway response.  No emails are sent, no exceptions are logged.

Regular pages return immediately with the responses I expect.  It appears to exhibit the bad behavior only if an exception is thrown.

What might cause such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  The firewall wasn't allowing outbound SMTP connections.  Django hung trying to send the email.

Answer (score 0):

At first I would have increased `nginx`:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
proxy_read_timeout 300s;
```

and `gunicorn` settings:

```
--timeout 180
```

Maybe it's would help to handle some exceptions in log files;